# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when delete document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making a webchat site. This is my sample code.

```
const result = await Room.findOne({
    name: roomName
});
if (result) {
    result.users.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (element === userName) {
            result.users.splice(index, 1);
            result.save();
            return;
        }
    });
    if (!result.users.length) {
        Room.findOneAndDelete({
            name: result.name
        }, function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

This code is for when the user gets out of the room, removes username in the room, and if their room has no user, remove the room.

Currently, My code deletes well... But, I always get this warning.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: VersionError: No matching document
>   found for id "5ecf2ade55c7db23747300e8" version 0 modifiedPaths
>   "users"

At first, I thought the `findOneAndDelete` function was called twice, but after checking it through the console, it doesn't seem to be. I made this using `Express` and `Mongoose`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per mongoose documentation, you have to call exec() method when using async/await.

`await MyModel.findOne({}).exec()`

Check this link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html